# Viewing Collada with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, collada

I'd like to create a Viewer for Collada files, my question is, is there any native support for this in WPF?

I am quite new to the 3D-parts of WPF so I don't know how everything works. So I'd like to know if it is even possible and if so, how hard is it? Examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since COLLADA defines an open standard XML schema for exchanging digital assets among various graphics software applications, You can parse as an XML Schema.

You can find a collade parser here - [Simple Collada Parser](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2008/02/20/3d-silverlight-10-simple-collada-parser/)

Please check this - [C# kickstart for loading the xmlNodes of a collada document](https://collada.org/public_forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=248).

**UPDATE:**

Check this link - [Loading a Collada File in a DirectX application](http://blogs.msdn.com/guillaumerandon/archive/2006/08/29/729841.aspx)

Comment: Any suggestions on how this will be applied to WPF 3D ?